# Query admin boundary from GeoNames API by lat/lon and admin level

Tags: api, administrative-boundaries, geonames

I have a list of points (lat / lon coordinates) which represent centroids of admin boundaries for a given country and admin level, e.g. Afghanistan, admin level 1.
I need to get their GeoNames IDs (https://www.geonames.org/).

I know there is a dedicated API (https://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrysubdiv) to query admin data, but apparently it doesn't return GeoNames ID:

`http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision?lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=demo&level=2`

This will return:

```xml
<geonames>
  <countrySubdivision>
    <countryCode>AT</countryCode>
    <countryName>Austria</countryName>
    <adminCode1>07</adminCode1>
    <adminName1>Tyrol</adminName1>
    <code level="1" type="ISO3166-2">7</code>
    <adminCode2>706</adminCode2>
    <adminName2>Landeck</adminName2>
    <distance>0</distance>
  </countrySubdivision>
</geonames>
```

The question is: how can I get the GeoNames ID for a given admin level and lat/lon coordinates?